# Accessing Bigcommerce' s %%GLOBAL_CustomerId%% variable

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

How can I have access to bigcommerce's %%GLOBAL_CustomerId%% variable?

I create a sample template and logged in with as a user. That variable doesn't show up. Isn't it suppose to be a Global variable?

Background: I want to create an app for bigcommerce that can identify a user base on their customerID. If I can't grab that variable, you guys see any other way to work around this?

Comment: "While these variables are prefixed with the word GLOBAL, in fact, the availability of the data varies on a per session, layout, panel, and snippet basis. Visit Store-Wide Variables for the list of variables available from anywhere in the store, regardless of session status." -- Can you provide more detail about where you tried using this variable?

Comment: @Alyss: good quesiton, I created a template, much like page.html( default template) and just try to log out the customer id. 

More Detail: Let's say I want to build a very simple wishlist app. Once a user logs in, I want to associate his/her customer id with the data in our DB. That way, we can open a popup with all their favorite items in it. 

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not immediately clear in the docs, but you can use `%%GLOBAL_CurrentCustomerEmail%%` anywhere on the template to get the email address of the currently logged in user. 
 
If you need the customer's ID, then you can query the API with the email as a parameter. 
Personally, I'd rather "trust" the customer's email as a point of identification, because you never know if the Bigcommerce ID's may get changed or not *(example: Customers are deleted and then reimported, now having brand new ID's)*.

On a subject of security though, you cannot trust client side data, and should attempt to mitigate fraudulent requests through the use of a CSRF token or some similar measure. Otherwise, anyone can send you an email address and receive back a list of that person's favorite products -- golden information for say, a targeted advertising company, or just your suspicious next-door neighbor Joe who seems to always be conveniently checking his mail right when you get home from work, but never says anything when you walk by, not even a wave or a smile, despite the fact that you all have been neighbors for quite some time now. Like, should I say something? 
Hahaha, I kid I kid.